# How do I get VS 2017 to install the dependencies for packages that I am trying to install?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, dependencies, nuget, installation

I was following a Lynda tutorial that was showing how to add versioning to my APIs.  It told me to install the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.  I tried that and it gave me an error because it needed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.  So I tried to install that package, and, again, another error because it needed another package.

So I started googling for a way to make VS 2017 pull in dependencies with NuGet installation.  None of the answers that I found were helpful.  I’ve tried managing as packageReference and packages.config.  “Allow format selection on first package install” is unchecked.  And so on.

So I decided to just power through and add all the dependencies manually.  I had to install 29 packages.  It took me over half an hour, not including time spent chasing the cat up and down the stairs screaming at the top of my lungs.

Is there some switch I forgot to flip, or some options I didn't add, or does Microsoft really think we might want the option to install a package without installing its dependencies?

Comment: How did you install the nuget packages, using nuget package management UI or command line in the Package manage console?

Comment: I right-click on the project -> Manage NuGet Packages and then search for the package and click install.

Comment: Strange, NuGet will automatically install the dependencies required by the package. What is your Visual Studio 2017 version and could you reproduce this issue with a new blank Projects/solution?

Comment: My VS 2017 is pretty new, I just installed it last week.  Version 15.9.4 with .NET framework 4.7.03056.  I just started a brand new ASP.NET Core Web Application and selected API.  The first thing I did was get into NuGet and try to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.  It gave me the option to install "Latest stable 3.1.1", which I tried to install.

Comment: It gave me "Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.  Install/reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions 2.2.0 directly to project WebApplication1 to resolve this issue."

Comment: Also:  WebApplication1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning 3.1.1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions (>= 2.2.0) 
 WebApplication1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0).

Comment: This is exactly what keeps happening.  I have to keep drilling down until something actually installs, then I can start moving back up through the list of dependencies until I can install the one I originally wanted.

Comment: Please add this errors to the question. This is a known problem. In . NET Core, the warning `NU1605` is treated as error by default. Go to **project properties** and remove this warning from *warnings as error*.

Comment: I tried that and nothing changed.  So I deleted the app and started a completely new one, same type as before.  The first thing I did was go to Properties -> Build and set "Treat warnings as errors" to "None" (it was originally treating NU1605 as an error).  Then I tried to add the same package, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning, and I got the exact same errors, EXCEPT that the code had changed to NU1107.

Comment: I googled for that error, and most of what I found referred to Newtonsoft.Json being the wrong version, but I don't even have that package installed.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT, another interesting datapoint; I was playing around with the above situation.  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning's latest version was 3.1.1, so I tried to install 3.1.0 instead, same error.  Then I tried to install 3.0.0 and it installed without error.  Of course, the package manager immediately reported that I needed an update on that package, and, predictably, when I tried to update it I got the same error as I got above.  So it looks like some kind of odd versioning snafu with the dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get VS 2017 to install the dependencies for packages that I am trying to install?

I have reproduced this issue on my side. This is the correct behavior for nuget. That because the package which you want to install have a indirect dependency `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions (>= 2.2.0)`.

Note: (Version need **>= 2.2.0**).

However, the default package for the .net core API project also have same indirect dependency `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0)` with version limit **(>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0)**.

Note: version limit **(>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0)**.

It conflict with dependency of package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning`. That the reason why nuget not install the dependencies for package.

**To resolve this issue**, we just need to update the target framework (*Right click project->Properties->Target Framework*) from **.NET Core 2.1** to **.NET Core 2.2** for your .net core API project.

If you do not have the version 2.2.0, please download it from here and install it:

[.NET SDKs for Visual Studio](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral)

After update the target framework to 2.2, the default package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` will be update to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0`, which dependency update to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions(>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0)`. So it compatible with the dependencies of the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning 3.1.1`.

Now I can install the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning 3.1.1` with its dependency.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or, in my case, where I couldn't upgrade target frameworks to 2.2 (and had to use 2.1), I had to downgrade my NuGet libraries versions from the latest to 2.1 compatible versions, which makes sense. Luckily, for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`, that very helpfully was the latest 2.1.* version -- that is, their versions matched the .NET Core major & minor versioning numbers. Thanks!